# How to programatically paste to terminal without executing?

Tags: bash, terminal, copy-paste

Is it possible to type / paste something to the console without executing the command? Something that would emulate the normal `Ctrl / Cmd + c`, `Ctrl / Cmd + v` where the text is put on the current line without being executed so the user can continue typing, deleting, etc.

For example I have the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "foo" | pbcopy

pbpaste
```

Now when I run this, it just echoes `foo%` and goes on the next line.

Also, even if this would work, I would prefer a solution that works on both mac os and ubuntu (as far as I know pbcopy does not come pre-installed on all linux distros).

**EDIT**

Edit to explain the scenario better. Imagine the script above is called `foo.sh`. You run the script `./foo.sh` and when it finishes you have a new prompt with only the text `"foo"|`. The `|` represents the cursor.

Comment: `foo%`? where does the `%` come from? So you just want the copied text to be available in another variable?

Comment: `echo -n` means echo without a newline and this is how my terminal interprets this, by putting that `%`. I do not want to save to any variable. I just want to put the text on the command line without executing it. Exactly how you would copy "foo" from a file and then use Ctrl+v to the terminal.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `%` is not expected in `bash` shell atleast, it should have just had `foo`, are you using a different shell? `zsh` may be?

Comment: Can you use your command history (bash: arrow keys or CTRL-R) ?

Comment: @Inian, Yes I use zsh and this is how it interprets it. If I use the same command in bash, it prepends foo to my prompt `foobash-3.2$`, still not what I want

Comment: @WalterA yes I can... no sure how this helps though :)

Comment: @skamsie: The `bash` behavior is right here. It does not prepend the text `foo`, the `pbpaste` has pasted the output without trailing newlines, then the next terminal prompt has appeared. Isn't it what you expect/

Comment: @Inian If you copy a word with your mouse and then click in the terminal and do Ctrl + p or right mouse click 'paste' you do not get a new terminal prompt, you only see the text there! This is exactly the behaviour I am trying to emulate.

Comment: Do you want to pre-populate the input buffer so that the user can optionally edit it and then send it?

Comment: @n.m yes, I have updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/johnlane/6bdeac9dd5a7b0c60820) contains examples in several languages using two different methods.

Answer (score 2):

So...  You already know about `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` in macOS. You probably want to know about [`xclip`](https://github.com/astrand/xclip), which is a similar interface to X selections ("the clipboard") from the command line.

Each system (Aqua and X) handles clipboard data structures differently, and I'm not aware of any single tool which will function this way on both platforms. That said, you can perhaps write scripts that are portable between both systems:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if type xclip >/dev/null; then
        clip_copy="xclip"
        clip_paste="xclip -o"
elif type pbcopy >/dev/null ; then
        clip_copy="pbcopy"
        clip_paste="pbpaste"
else
        echo "ERROR: no clipboard functions. Where am I?" >&2
        exit 1
fi
```

Also note that pbcopy/pbpaste support different *data types*, whereas `xclip` just deals with text.

That said, both of these functions deal with *stdin* and *stdout*. If you want to actually *simulate keypresses* (as your edit appears to imply), you need another tool.

In the Mac world, a number of options exist. Cliclick works well for me. This tool has full mouse support, but also has an option `t:`, which will simulate keyboard input. It seems reasonable that one might `cliclick t:"$(pbpaste)"`, though I've never tried it.

You can also use AppleScript to print arbitrary text:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "Hello world."'
```

In X, [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) seems to work.

```
$ xdotool type "Hello world."
```

To make a script which might run in both macOS and X environments, you could key on the output of `uname -s`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case "$(uname -s)" in
  Darwin)
    clip_copy="pbcopy"           # note: $clip_copy isn't used in this script.
    clip_paste="pbpaste"
    type_cmd="osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"%s\"'"
    ;;
  *)
    clip_copy="xclip"
    clip_paste="xclip -o"
    type_cmd='xdotool type "%s"'
    ;;
esac

text="$($clip_paste)"

printf "$type_cmd" "${text//[!A-Za-z0-9. ]/}" | sh
```

Note: untested. YMMV. May contain nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a gist in the comments I found a thread on stack exchange that helped me answer my own question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213821.

I am only interested in supporting sh, bash, zsh so the following solution works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(echo $ZSH_VERSION)" ]; then
    print -z $@
else
    # assume bash or sh
    bind '"\e[0n": "'"$*"'"'; printf '\e[5n'
fi
```

Call with `source inject.sh echo foo`